# Auto-complete mode on Emacs For Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, autocomplete

I use the same emacs config in my windows 7 and osx.

By default, I don't blink the cursor by setting `(blink-cursor-mode 0)`.

In osx, when I type a non-candicate of auto-complete(for example, typing a new function name or some `fdsafdsafdsa`), at this moment, auto-complete matches nothing but each time I type a char, the cursor will blink once as if it's trying to do completion. This just works fine in my windows 7.

Is there anything wrong with my osx or [Emacs For Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/)? What should I do to fix this since the cursor blinking too much is really upsetting me ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated ~ :)

Comment: It's probably blinking because auto-complete mode is doing something even though there is no suggestion popping up.  I'd send the developer an e-mail letting him / her know.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for your comment! :) I also guess that it's doing something, may be it should stop doing it since the first mismatch char or something else. But I wonder why the cursor doesn't blink during the period on windows...

Comment: Are you using Carbon Emacs or Aquamacs (www.aquamacs.org)?  It looks like you're using the former from the download page.  Have you tried the latter?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Emacs on both systems?  And the same version of the autocomplete library?

Comment: @Dan I haven't tried Aquamacs since it seems that it comes with many packages.

Comment: @pcurry Both are 24.3 and the newest stable auto-complete from elpa.

Comment: It's seem that ac will keep calling `ac-cleanup` when each char is typed in even there's no available candidate. And the first two lines `(if ac-cursor-color (set-cursor-color ac-cursor-color))` in `ac-cleanup` make the cursor blinking all the time. Now I just comment out these two lines for a quick and dirty solution. Maybe the cursor blinks in windows too, but I really can't feel it in win 7. In mac, that's too much.

Answer (score 0):

On my test OS X system, I turned the blinking cursor off by setting its 'off' character to be equal to its 'on' character.  This can be done with the Emacs setting 'blink-cursor-alist'.  The format is '(ON-TYPE . OFF-TYPE)'.  For me, the help was in section '14.20 Displaying the Cursor', in the on-line manual. See:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cursor-Display.html

Comment: So that doesn't so much stop blinking as render the blinks invisible.  Still, decent hack.